# sqlite3 cursor.fetchall() returns an empty array

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm ssh'd into a remote server, and there I created two python files as a test: one to create a database, and one to read data from it.

The script that creates the database

```
import os
import sqlite3

# set up database
conn = sqlite3.connect('Materials.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def createTable():
        c.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS images")
        c.execute("CREATE TABLE images(ID TEXT, url TEXT)")
createTable()

path = os.getcwd()

imagepath = "/home/rootadmin/1080_images"
imagedir = os.listdir(imagepath)
for image in range(0,len(imagedir)):
        c.execute('INSERT INTO images(ID, url) VALUES(?,?)',(imagedir[image],'www.google.com'))
        print(imagedir[image])
```

Here the print commands the data that is required, e.g. it prins the ID's of the images.

In my script to read the data from the db:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('Materials.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('SELECT ID FROM images')
objectId = c.fetchall()
print(objectId)
```

I have a limited knowledge of sqlite3, but I would expect the print command in the second script to print the ID's found in the images table, from the Materials.db, yet it returns an empty array.

Comment: your `for` loops could also be improved btw. do `for item in imagedir:` and in the loop use the new variable `item` instead of `imagedir[image]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to commit your transaction when inserting:

```
for image in range(0,len(imagedir)):
    c.execute('INSERT INTO images(ID, url) VALUES(?,?)',(imagedir[image],'www.google.com'))
    print(imagedir[image])
conn.commit()
```

or [use the connection as a context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager) to auto-commit when the context exits:

```
with conn:
    for image in range(0,len(imagedir)):
        c.execute('INSERT INTO images(ID, url) VALUES(?,?)',(imagedir[image],'www.google.com'))
        print(imagedir[image])
```

This also ensures that the transaction is explicitly rolled back if there was an exception.

Comment: This works, thank you. Could you elaborate on using connection as a context manager?

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen: I linked to the relevant documentation section.

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen: for details on what context managers do, see the [reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers).